# Token timeout issue when using Silverlight with ADFS passive federation

Tags: silverlight, wif, adfs

I am using passive federated authentication with Silverlight, WIF and ADFS.
I followed the Training Toolkit example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/identitytrainingcourse_silverligthandidentity2010_topic2

Everything works fine. Claims come back, the user is authenticated, etc. It is working absolutely fine with RIA services.

The problem comes after using the application for 1 hour. The token seems to become invalid and all subsequent calls from the Silverlight client to the domain service fail.

I have checked the ADFS settings, they are all defaults.

- Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrusts shows that TokenLifetime = 0
- Get-ADFSProperties shows that SsoLifetime = 480 (which I assume is 8 hours).

I am using the assemblies included with the training kit: **SL.IdentityModel** & **SL.IdentityModel.Server**.

Online I have seen people making references to setting *freshness values* however this doesn't seem to apply as everything is auto setup by the SL.IdentityModel.Server services.

Comment: From using twitter, it appears that after the 1 hour mark it requests a new token. But all subsequent domain service calls result in a 302 redirect. Which causes Silverlight to fail. Pasting the URL into a browser results in the redirect and then the data downloading. It just seems to be Silverlight that isn't responding well to it.